# Array of string not binding to the listview

Tags: arrays, listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to bind an array to list view. It's not binding and showing blank. I used Model class to place array.

**View Model:**

```
public class RunningLateOptions
    {
      public string[] runningLateOptions = new[] { "30 Mins", "1 Hour", "1:30 Hour", "2 Hours" };
        public string[] runningLateOption
        {
           get{ return runningLateOptions; }
        }
    }
```

**XAML code:**

```
<ListView x:Name="RunningLateOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding RunningLateOptions}" ItemSelected="runningLateSelectedItem">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Label x:Name="listItems" Text="{Binding runningLateOption}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm not able to understand what's wrong with this. Help me.

Comment: Where is this array of strings? in your ViewModel or Xaml.cs?

Comment: array of strings placed in View model

Comment: Can you show me your VM code quickly

Comment: I provide my VM. Please check the code.

Comment: Did the below solution work for you!

Comment: you are binding to `RunningLateOptions` (capital 'R') but your property is named `runningLateOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type  **ItemsSource** of **ListView** or **CollectionView** should be a list which implement the Interface **IEnumerable** .

So we normally set it as an `ObservableCollection<T>` or `List<T>` .

In your case , you could set the ItemsSource of the ListView like

```
public ObservableCollection<string> RunningLateOptions {get; set;}
```

ObservableCollection has implemented the Interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So you don't need to implement it any more .

For more details about ListView you could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

```
<ListView x:Name="RunningLateOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding RunningLateOptions}" ItemSelected="runningLateSelectedItem">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Label x:Name="listItems" Text="{Binding runningLateOption}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackLayout>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You could share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: I provided the Listview and View Model above. I not using except that.
Just that array is not binding to the listview.

Comment: Provide the screen shot of the effect on your device .

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the xaml as follows:-

```
<ListView x:Name="RunningLateOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding runningLateOption}" ItemSelected="runningLateSelectedItem">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Label x:Name="listItems" Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Let me know if you face more difficulties.

Comment: Did you modify the ItemSource ItemsSource="{Binding runningLateOption}" ?

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel, you can do that by using MVVMHelpers Nuget Package and use it as properties are declared in ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

I gave the array of strings in the CS file and bind to listview by using itemsource.
I didn't use any View model here.

**CS code:**

```
string[] runningLateOptions = { "30 Mins", "1 Hour", "1:30 Hour", "2 Hours"  };
RunningLateOptions.ItemsSource = runningLateOptions;
```

**XAML code:**

```
<ListView x:Name="RunningLateOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemSelected="runningLateSelectedItem">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="listItems" Text="{Binding}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
         </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

TextCell not providing the HorizontalTextAlignment attribute. That's why I used view cell for the label.

Thanks for helping me.
[Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he8XS.png)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .